# Android SQLite tables not deleted when Application uninstalled on actual device

Tags: android, sqlite

Fresh installation of the application still retrieving old data on Phone but not on Emulator. Please see the screenshots below...

Emulator:

[image]

Logcat from Emulator:

[image]

The same application when run on the actual device (on a fresh install), gives me this:

[image]

Logcat from Device:

[image]

I uninstalled the app from the device, many number of times, restarted the device, cleared cache, but nothing seems to remove the database from device. This is the first time i am looking at such kind of scenario, so please if someone can help me figure this out, its much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a device running Android M (API 23+)? You may be seeing the effects of an auto-backup: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Comment: Yes i am using Marshmallow 6.0.1. How can i get past this auto-backup?

Comment: You can set `allowBackup` to `false` in your Manifest

Comment: Okie thanks.. that worked. I had android:fullBackupContent set to true in my app. Removing that along with android:allowBackup="false" solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest add this line under application tag

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

Comment: Thanks, i had android:fullBackupContent set to true in my app. Removing that along with android:allowBackup="false" solved the issue.